# Are potato fruits (not "potatoes") edible?

Tags: potatoes

My uncle has a fairly expansive garden and he grows potatoes. He asked a question, that being if they'd ever seen tomatoes growing from their potato plants. I've done some research (and remembered some things I had been told), mostly coming to find out that potatoes and tomatoes are both of the nightshade family and so they share some similar traits (one of which that they have similar fruit, i.e. tomatoes and my uncles potato fruits).

My question is whether they're edible or not? (They're from the nightshade family, they could kill you for all I know)

If they ARE edible, how could you cook them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot; they are full of solanine, which is poisonous. You can use the seeds however to grow new potatoes, though they won't breed true to the parent. This website has some great information: http://tinyfarmblog.com/potato-fruit/

Comment: Actually, the fruit were the reason potatoes were introduced so late into western cuisine - legend has it that they first tried the fruit and keeled over dead.